# How to tell if a directed graph has a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, cyclic-groups

If I have the directed graph here:

[image]

I am confused whether or not this is a cycle or not. Because in the underlying graph, this is a 3-cycle for sure, but in the directed graph, there is no cycle if we take into consideration the arrows.

In terms of directed trees, does a cycle count as the underlying version or with respect to the arrows? In other words, is this example a directed tree?

Thanks

Comment: It is not a directed cycle, but the graph is not a directed tree: a directed tree is a directed graph that would be a tree if you forgot about the directions.

Comment: Also there are two paths from A to B.